# Could this be the new clearfix?

Tags: css, clearfix

Is there a more simplified way to use `.clearfix`?

old:

```css
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

My new clear fix:

```css
.coreys-clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
```

I put this through a validator and I had no errors. Does anyone else know of or see any reason why this can not be used? it only saves 3 lines of code and a `.`, but still.

Comment: The simplest way to use clearfix is to not use clearfix.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so, no.

The reason for the dot, is to make the `.clearfix:after` work in legacy browsers.

Nicholas Gallagher explains why:

> Firefox < 3.5 will benefit from using Thierry’s method with the addition of visibility:hidden to hide the inserted character. This is because legacy versions of Firefox need content:"." to avoid extra space appearing between the body and its first child element, in certain circumstances (e.g., jsfiddle.net/necolas/K538S/.)

This is why `content` is not empty, and the three remaining lines (`visibility`, `line-height` and `height`) is to make sure the clearfix doesn't actually take up room in your layout.

Actually, Nicholas has made a new clearfix, which does the same job with less bytes. Read up on it here: http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Good effort, though. :)

Comment: Although if one isn't targeting legacy browsers, there is no reason not to have empty content (which is *not* the same as *no* content).

Comment: That is true, but in this you save practically nothing from *not* targeting legacy browsers, so you might as well do it.

Comment: Thank you Nix. I am currently working on my own start up site and as witch the % of people missed by not supporting legacy browsers for my site will not currently affect it, I would hope.

Answer (score 1):

If you want support for older browsers, you'll need a more elaborate clearfix :

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

If you don't care about support for older browsers, this is the way to go :

```
.clearfix:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The dot is there for older browser support. If you don't need that, you can use the "new" one.

**[This answer actually explains it pretty nicely.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8554054/871050)**